# Server Error when logging in to a private docker registry from docker in docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-registry

I'm using boot2docker and docker 1.4.1 and I'm running a Jenkins container that also runs Docker as a host (also version 1.4.1). However when I try to login to my [Tutum](https://www.tutum.co/) private Docker registry using:

```
sudo docker login -u=username -p=**** -e=my@email.com tutum.co
```

I end up with the following error:

```
Server Error: Post https://tutum.co/v1/users/: dial tcp: lookup tutum.co on [192.168.1.1]:53
```

Everything works fine if I login from outside the Jenkins container. What is the reason for this and how do I get around it?

Update:

If I stop the Docker service inside the Jenkins container (`sudo service docker stop`) and start it using:

```
sudo docker -d &
```

I get some more detailed information:

```
INFO[0003] POST /v1.16/auth
INFO[0003] +job auth()
Get https://tutum.co/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup tutum.co on [192.168.1.1]:53: no such host
INFO[0005] -job auth() = ERR (1)
ERRO[0005] Handler for POST /auth returned error: Get https://tutum.co/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup tutum.co on [192.168.1.1]:53: no such host
ERRO[0005] HTTP Error: statusCode=404 Get https://tutum.co/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup tutum.co on [192.168.1.1]:53: no such host
FATA[0001] Error response from daemon: Get https://tutum.co/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup tutum.co on [192.168.1.1]:53: no such host
```

Comment: From inside the docker container (Jenkins) can you access tutum.co (ping/telnet/dnslookup...). It seems there is some DNS issue.

Comment: I can't "ping tutum.co" from inside the container nor outside. I can "ping www.tutum.co" though both from both inside the container and outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by changing the DNS server as Javier implied. Docker uses the DNS server specified in `/etc/resolv.conf` which pointed to `192.168.1.1`. I changed this `8.8.8.8` and afterwards I was able to login.

Update:

Today I tried to overwrite the `/etc/resolv.conf` file from `Dockerfile` but it turns out that Docker sets the DNS when the container is started. This means that the file `resolv.conf` file I've added from the `Dockerfile` is overwritten. The solution is to add `--dns 8.8.8.8` when the container is started. For example

```
docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 ubuntu:14.04 <some_command>
```